# Concat giving warnings and won't execute

Tags: angular, rxjs

The following method, with `forkJoin` works fine, but . . .

```
unifiedSearch : Function = (query: string) : Observable<UnifiedSearch> => {
  return forkJoin(this.searchService.gitSearch(query), this.codeSearchService.codeSearch(query))
  .map( (response : [GitSearch, GitCodeSearch]) => {
    return {
      'repositories' : response[0],
      'code': response[1]
    }
  })
}
```

. . . I tried to convert it to use `concat` as part of an assignment, but while it compiles, I get a bunch of warnings, and nothing renders in the browser.

```
unifiedSearch : Function = (query: string) : Observable<UnifiedSearch> => {
  return concat(this.searchService.gitSearch(query), this.codeSearchService.codeSearch(query))
  .map( (response) => {
    return {
      'repositories' : response[0],
      'code': response[1]
    }
  })
}
```

For reference, here is the 'UnifiedSearch' Interface:

```
import {GitSearch} from './git-search';
import { GitCodeSearch } from './git-code-search';

export interface UnifiedSearch {
    repositories: GitSearch,
    code: GitCodeSearch
}
```

If helpful, here are the warnings I receive:

`./node_modules/rxjs/Observable/of.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\Johnathan\advanced_angular\node_modules\rxjs\Observable\of.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\Johnathan\advanced_angular\node_modules\rxjs\Observable\concat.js
* C:\Users\Johnathan\advanced_angular\node_modules\rxjs\observable\of.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\Johnathan\advanced_angular\node_modules\@angular\common\@angular\common\http.es5.js`

Any ideas why the `concat` version doesn't work? Tks!

Answer (score 1):

`concat` and `forkJoin` work a bit differently.

`concat` emits every value from each source in order of emit and the order given as an argument to the `concat` operator. Once a source completes it moves to the next one in the source array.

`forkJoin` will give the last emitted values of each observable, then return those values in an array. It will wait until all the given observables complete before it emits.

Take the following for an example:

```js
const source1 = of(1, 2);
const source2 = of(3, 4);


concat(source1, source2).subscribe(v => console.log(v))
// output (each line is new emit)
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4

forkJoin(source1, source2).subscribe(v => console.log(v))
// output (each line is new emit)
// [2, 4]
```

You may want to look at using [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) to combine the emits from each source and emits the *combined latest values* each time one of the source observables emit. The difference between this and `forkJoin` is that `combineLatest` emits each time the source observables emit, whereas `forkJoin` only emits once all the source observables have completed.